# Fastest way to do min-max based on specific component of vectors in GLSL?

Tags: glsl, shader

I need to call this kind of function many many times in my GLSL code.

```
vec2 minx(vec2 a, vec2 b) {
    if (a.x < b.x) return a;
    else return b;
}
```

I'm concerned of the excessive branching. Is there a way to do this avoiding if-else constructs?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I suggest to use the GLSL functions [`mix`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/mix.xhtml) and [`step`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/step.xhtml).

[`mix`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/mix.xhtml) interpolates between 2 values according to a floating point interpolation value `a` in the range [0.0, 1.0]. If the `a` is equal 0.0 then the 1st value is returned and if the `a` is equal 1.0 then the 2nd value is returned.

[`step`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/step.xhtml) tests whether a value is less than an edge value. If it is less then 0.0 is returned, else 1.0 is returned.

If you combine the 2 functions your code will look like this:

```
vec2 minx(vec2 a, vec2 b)
{
    return mix( a, b, step( b.x, a.x ) );
}
```

Note, the result of [`step`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/step.xhtml) is either exactly 0.0 or exactly 1.0, this causes that [`mix`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/mix.xhtml) either returns the 1st value or returns the 2nd value.

Comment: Amazing! THank you.

Comment: Is there a way to "mix" structs in the same manner?

Comment: @EugZol no. [`mix`](https://registry.khronos.org/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/mix.xhtml) is an overloaded built-in function and works only with the basic GLSL types.